# Filter nested array data based on match

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I want to filter All taskLists data into **open** and **closed** tasklists using `status` key

```
var data = [{
  "createdOn": "Created on Jan 07, 2017",
  "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Jason",
    "status": "closed",
  },
  {
    "task": "Meeting with Ram",
    "status": "open",
  },
  ]
},
{
  "createdOn": "Created on Jan 08, 2017",
  "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Mike",
    "status": "open",
  },
  {
    "task": "Meeting with Smith",
    "status": "closed",
  },
  ]
}
];
```

I have tried with this:

```
console.log(_.filter(data, { taskList: [ { status: "open" } ]}));
```

**Actual Result:**

According to data, TaskList array contains 2 open status on Jan 07 and Jan 08. But I am getting an entire array of taskList.

```
0:{createdOn: "Created on Jan 07, 2017", taskList: Array(2)}
1:{createdOn: "Created on Jan 08, 2017", taskList: Array(2)}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
0:{createdOn: "Created on Jan 07, 2017", taskList: "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Ram",
    "status": "open",
  }} 
1:{createdOn: "Created on Jan 08, 2017", taskList: "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Mike",
    "status": "open",
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filter` is wrong.

```js
var data = [{
  "createdOn": "Created on Jan 07, 2017",
  "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Jason",
    "status": "closed",
  },
  {
    "task": "Meeting with Ram",
    "status": "open",
  },
  ]
},
{
  "createdOn": "Created on Jan 08, 2017",
  "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Mike",
    "status": "open",
  },
  {
    "task": "Meeting with Smith",
    "status": "closed",
  },
  ]
}
];
var newArray = data.filter(function (el) {
  el.taskList = el.taskList.filter(function(item)
  {
  return item.status == "open";
  });
  return el;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is fine if you want filter items that contains `status='open'`. If you want return modified object, its another story. This is ECMAS6 lodash/vanilla:

```js
// lodash
console.log(_.map(data, o => o.taskList = _.filter(o.taskList, { 'status': 'open' })));

// vanilla
console.log(data.map(o => o.taskList = o.taskList.filter(t => t.status == 'open')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{
  "createdOn": "Created on Jan 07, 2017",
  "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Jason",
    "status": "closed",
  },
  {
    "task": "Meeting with Ram",
    "status": "open",
  },
  ]
},
{
  "createdOn": "Created on Jan 08, 2017",
  "taskList": [{
    "task": "Meeting with Mike",
    "status": "open",
  },
  {
    "task": "Meeting with Smith",
    "status": "closed",
  },
  ]
}
];
</script>
```